# Testing Sinatra REST API Methodology

Tags: api, rest, testing, rspec, sinatra

I would like to know best practice on testing a REST API (in this case, using Sinatra and Rspec). The obvious problem is that, if you have a test that checks `GET /users` for a user list, you would like go through the stages of creating a user, running the test, then destroying the user. However, if the create/destroy steps are also API-dependent, you end up either breaking the rule of ordered-based testing, or testing multiple things in one test (eg. did it add a user?.. does `GET /users` return a user list?.. did it delete the user?).

Answer (score 0):

You could use FactoryGirl. In your tests you can create Users via your API or create stubs with FG which you then delete, modify and so on. FG is a very flexible ORM testing helper that works great for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with @three - use [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)!

As an example (firstly, define a sample objects):

```
FactoryGirl.define do

   sequence(:random_ranking) do |n|
      @random_rankings ||= (1..10000).to_a.shuffle
      @random_rankings[n]
   end

   factory :todo do
      title { Faker::Lorem.sentence}
      id { FactoryGirl.generate(:random_ranking) }
      completed [true, false].sample
      completed_at Time.new
      created_at Time.new
      updated_at Time.new
   end

end
```

And in your spec test, describe your list action:

```
describe 'GET #index' do

    before do

      @todos = FactoryGirl.create_list(:todo, 10)

      @todos.each do |todo|
        todo.should be_valid
      end

      get :index, :format => :json

    end


    it 'response should be OK' do
      response.status.should eq(200)
    end

    it 'response should return the same json objects list' do

      response_result = JSON.parse(response.body)

      # these should do the same
      # response_result.should =~ JSON.parse(@todos.to_json)
      response_result.should match_array(JSON.parse(@todos.to_json))

    end

end
```